How can I separate RowNumber counting?
I'm trying to create a point in time hierarchy in my organization.  The problem I'm running into are some folks have reported to the same manager more than once in their career.  I tried doing a row_number on their ID and manager, but as expected, the counting continues when they report back to the same manager.  Some sample data:



ID
Manager ID
EFF_DT
EXP_DT
RWNUM




1
2
5/24/2020
6/30/2020
1


1
2
7/1/20202
8/25/2020
2


1
2
8/26/2020
12/9/2020
3


1
3
12/10/2020
1/29/2021
1


1
3
1/30/2021
5/30/2021
2


1
3
5/31/2021
7/15/2021
3


1
4
7/16/2021
8/30/2021
1


1
4
9/01/2021
9/15/2021
1


1
2
9/16/2021
12/31/2021
4


1
2
1/1/2022
3/31/2022
5



So when this employee reported back to manager 2, the rownumber counted to 4 and 5.  Is there a way in SQL to have it reset and count as 1 and 2?
Sample of the desired end data:



ID
Manager ID
EFF_DT
EXP_DT




1
2
5/24/2020
12/9/2020


1
3
12/10/2020
7/15/2021


1
4
7/16/2021
9/15/2021


1
2
9/16/2021
3/31/2022



I figured the best way was to use window functions, but I can't figure out a simple way to get this result.  All suggestions are welcome, thank you!
I created the tables wrong, and went to edit them.  Stackoverflow autosaved the edit when I finished the 1st one, and wouldn't let me save this edit on the 2nd table until I made the body thoroughly different, so I'm adding this paragraph to hopefully satisfy that requirement.

Is your goal just to collapse those contiguous rows into a single row?

Not exactly, if the employee reported to the same manager again I want a 2nd row, much like the 2nd table shown above for Manager2

Far as I can see, the answer below gives you exactly that.

If you are wanting to collapse contiguous rows into a single row, you can use Teradata normalize function. It only works with periods, so we have to convert your dates into a period.
select
id,
manager_id,
begin(prd) as eff_dt,
last(prd) as exp_dt
from (
select normalize
id,
manager_id,
period(eff_dt,exp_dt + 1) as prd
from
<your table>) t


Based on the "desired result" this is the correct answer. If you really need to do the ROW_NUMBER for some other reason, Teradata supports a RESET WHEN clause for window functions which can be used to decide when to start over (e.g. using LAG to look for non-consecutive dates).

After playing with it a bit I couldn't get the normalize function to work for my data set.  It kept giving the same result, just added a new column with the period.  The reset when worked great though, thank you for your answer!
